# Assigning base class members in copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, initializer-list

I've got a class that inherits from a MSFT class, and therefore cannot be changed, and I'd like my derived class to have identical behavior for its copy constructor and copy assignment operator. The trouble I'm having is that in the copy constructor, you are free to invoke a constructor for the base class in the initializer list, but in the operator, this is not an option. How can I properly recreate this behavior in the assignment operator? <strike>Is it sufficient to just call the base class's constructor in the body of the operator overload?</strike>

Additional note: the base class inherits from CObject, which has operator=() and the copy constructor as private and unimplemented methods, so unfortunately any calls to those will result in a compile error.

I've provided a simplified code scenario below:

Class declarations:

```cpp
class Base    
{
protected:
    int baseInt;
public:
    Base(int);
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(const Derived& other);
    Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs);
private:
    int derivedInt;
}
```

Derived class member functions:

```cpp
// Copy Constructor
Derived(const Derived& other) : Base(5)
{
    derivedInt = other.derivedInt;
}

// Copy Assignment Operator
Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        derivedInt = other.derivedInt;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated syntax and added CObject note

Comment: `Base(5);` just creates a temporary `Base` object and then immediately destroys it...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's what I suspected would happen :/ I'm not too familiar with how to recreate the actions of an initializer list, so it was a shot in the dark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the general case, you do that either by explicitly calling operator= for the base class subobject, or by using the copy&swap idiom, if available:

```
//explicit call to base operator=
Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs)
{
  Base::operator=(rhs); //
  derivedInt = rhs.derivedInt;
  return *this;
}


//or copy&swap:
Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs)
{
  Derived tmp(rhs); //copy
  tmp.swap(*this);
  return *this;
}

void swap(Derived& other)   
{
  Base::swap(other);
  std::swap(derivedInt,other.derivedInt);
}
```

**Update:** since your base class is not meant to be copy-assigned, your derived class should not be copy-assigned either. There are some cases where classes contain noncopyable parts but are perfectly copyable. In those cases the noncopyable part is something that does not directly contribute to the class objects' state, e.g. a unique ID. Then those parts will normally not be changed during assignment. However, in those cases the noncopyable parts should not be contained by inheritance but rather by aggregation.

Shortly said: Iheritance means "is-A" relationship. Your Base cannot be copied. Your Derived is a Base. Thus your Derived cannot be copied either.

Comment: While this seems that it would work in the majority of cases, I am inheriting ultimately from CObject, whose assignment operator/copy constructor is private. Also, `swap()` is not implemented in the base class, nor any of its bases, so that will not work either :/ I've updated my question to reflect this

Comment: OK, thanks. My static analysis tool complained about the lack of `operator=`, so I assumed it had to be there despite being private in the base. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes and no. Your static analysis tool complains and some compilers warn about the undefined `operator=`, because it cannot be generated by the compiler like usual. That is due to the noncopyable base class, making your derived class *implicitly* noncopyable. For readability and to silence the complaints of your tools, you could explicitly say that you *know* that your derived isn't copable and that it's on purpose - by declaring the copyctor and assignment operator private (C++03) or explicitly deleting them (C++11)

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived& rhs)
{
    Base::operator=(rhs);
    derivedInt = rhs.derivedInt;
    return *this;
}
```